# How do I override/reset android EditText default colors?

Tags: android, colors, android-edittext

So I am using a custom color scheme with my own colors in it. But the problem is that Although I have set the color_primary and color_secondary, when I drag in a new EditText view, the underlines, text colors and so on are still the default.
**Is there a way to set my colors so that All my EditText views display them (instead of changing every View one be one.)?**
Is there a default file from which the buttons take their default color values ... I was hoping if that was the case, I could just change that file itself.

Answer (score 1):

you can create style for TextInutLayout or EditText and apply the style to every Edit Text.

Below is the code for TextInput layout

first, create one common style for EditText

```
 <style name="TextInputFieldStyle" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorSecondaryText</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <!--<item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/TextHintAppearance</item>-->
</style>
```

and apply the style:  style="@style/TextInputFieldStyle"

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/ifsc_til"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            style="@style/TextInputFieldStyle"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorSecondaryText">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorBlackAlpha20"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/edit_text_padding_bottom"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                tools:text="Full Name" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Is there a default file from which the buttons take their default color values ... I was hoping if that was the case, I could just change that file itself.

Comment: colorAccent is the default color for EditText line color. i.e, defined in color.xml